# Question marked as duplicate, fair, but the link is wrong

Tags: discussion

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329253/how-do-i-protect-my-code-if-i-hire-a-freelancer-overseas
was closed as duplicate.

The duplicate url: [How do you prevent the piracy of your software?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/how-do-you-prevent-the-piracy-of-your-software)

Has no reason at all being there. The question is clearly not a duplicate of the one linked as a duplicate and wastes the time of people clicking on it for information.

How can I change the url to the right duplicate url: [How to prevent code from leaking outside work?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170246/how-to-prevent-code-from-leaking-outside-work) ?

Comment: Cast a custom moderator flag against the question, and explain the problem.